# FirebaseError: Firebase: Need to provide options. How to fix this problem?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native

I am experiencing some firebase error and need some help on my React-Native application. How do i solve this issue?

> FirebaseError: Firebase: Need to provide options, when not being deployed to hosting via source. (app/no-options)., js engine: hermes

```
//App.js
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import LoginScreen from './screens/LoginScreen';
import HomeScreen from './screens/HomeScreen';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';


const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator ();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen  options= {{headerShown:false}} name="LoginScreen" component={LoginScreen}/>
        <Stack.Screen  options={{headerShown:false}} name="HomeScreen" component={HomeScreen}/>
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

Firebase.js

```
// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need

import {initializeApp} from 'firebase/app';
import {getFirestore} from 'firebase/firestore';
import {getAuth} from 'firebase/auth';

// TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "AI***",
  authDomain: "eshopmobile-fb508.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "eshopmobile-fb508",
  storageBucket: "eshopmobile-fb508.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "734223583165",
  appId: "1:734223583165:web:6849ecf86323894686b4d4"
};



  // initialize firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig, "eshopmobile");
console.log(app);

const db = getFirestore(app);
const auth = getAuth(app);
```

// newest firebase configuration

```
// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';




// TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyCA6GQQRquvLLrdyO8wuYUc0s6FWGKF5-Y",
  authDomain: "eshopmobile-fb508.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://eshopmobile-fb508-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "eshopmobile-fb508",
  storageBucket: "eshopmobile-fb508.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "734223583165",
  appId: "1:734223583165:web:6849ecf86323894686b4d4"
};

// Initialize Firebase

  // initialize firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export { auth, db };
```

What am missing from the given config file?

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing the modular syntax of v9 and later of the Firebase SDKs with the namespaced syntax of older version. You should use one or the other, not a mix of both.

To upgrade the code to only use the modular syntax, initialize the app as shown in the documentation on [installing and initializing the SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#add-sdks-initialize):

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';

// TODO: Replace the following with your app's Firebase project configuration
const firebaseConfig = {
  //...
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```

So `initializeApp` is a top-level function here, not a method on `firebase`.

For you this should be:

```
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```

Comment: i have tried this but i was not successful, what am i missing?